# getting a segmentation fault when trying to read a file?

Tags: c, file, io, segmentation-fault

I am passing in argv[1] for the fileName and i am getting a segfault but i do not know why. i am using a linked list to hold instances of a car struct that holds 2 chars and an int. i feel like the problem is in my fscanf statement but i am not sure.

```
void readFile(List *north, List *east, List *south, List *west, char *fileName) {
    char *file = fileName;
    FILE *fp = fopen(file, "r");

    if(!fp) {
        printf("File could not be opened...");
        return;
    }

    while(!feof(fp)) {
        Car *temp = NULL; //Initialize a blank car
        fscanf(fp, "%s %s %d", &temp->direc, &temp->turn, &temp->time); //scan the direction path and time
        //into the Car Node

        //Add to North List
        if(temp->direc == 'N') {
            insertBack(north, temp);
        }

        //Add to East List
        if(temp->direc == 'E') {
            insertBack(east, temp);
        }

        //Add to South List
        if(temp->direc == 'S') {
            insertBack(south, temp);
        }

        //Add to West List
        if(temp->direc == 'W') {
            insertBack(west, temp);
        }

        else {
            printf("Something went wrong...");
            return;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Please compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then **use the debugger `gdb`**

Comment: I am using a mac and was having trouble getting it to work

Comment: You should be able to use `gdb` in a terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `Car *temp = NULL; //Initialize a blank car`

You are not initializing a "blank" car here. The `temp` variable is just `NULL`. Use `malloc` to allocate space before you do `fscanf`:

`Car *temp = malloc(sizeof(Car));`

If by "blank" you mean zeroing out the allocated space, use `calloc`.

Comment: im feeling special, thanks